# sfdisk и close device failed: Input/output error

Tags: linux, fdisk

Достался сервер в наследство, подключаюсь к нему через PXE с Slackware,
пытаюсь разбить жесткий диск на разделы для дальнейшей работы:

```
sfdisk /dev/sda << EOF
2048,8388608,S
,104857600,L
,,E
,20971520,L
,20971520,L
,20971520,L
,,L
EOF
fi
```

при этом возникает проблема:

```
/dev/sda: close device failed: Input/output error.
```

Не могу пока разобраться с причиной этой ошибки. Почему так происходит?

Comment: Нехорошая ошибка. Возможно винт своё отжил.

Answer (score 0):

Раз она пишет:

> close device failed

значит она не может закрыть диск. Значит - диск у Вас ПРИмонтирован.
Его обязательно надо ОТмонтировать.

Если на нём корневая ФС, значит надо загружаться (LiveCD) с компашки или флэшки. 
Дальше смотреть список устройств (можно - по меткам, если они есть), искать то, что было */dev/sda* и пилить его...